# Swing event architecture

Tags: java, swing, events, architecture

I'm building a rich client application based on Swing. And I'm wondering what is the best architecture for event's handling.

My classes are :

- MyFrame
- FirstPanel, with a jbutton
- SecondPanel with a jLabel

I start the application with a FirstPanel within a MyFrame.

Then, I add an action listener to the button in the FirstPanel, and I whant this action to (1) close the FirstPane then (2) open a new SecondPanel in the running MyFrame

How to do it ?

**Edit - Example**

I want to show at startup a list of users, stored in a file, then the user click on his name or click on "new user". When he clicks on "new user", a second panel appears, with a form to create a new user and store it in the file.

In this example, MyFrame is the main frame, created by the main() method.

Then the ListUsersPanel appears.

Then, the NewUserPanel appears if I click on "new user".

My question is : how do I design my classes/listeners to manage all this ?

** Edit - example 2 **
What if I have a JFrame that contains 2 JPanels, and I want a button in Panel1 that change a label in Panel2 ?

Comment: you are already describing the event architecture...

Answer (score 2):

In this situation normally you just use a modal JDialog to display the new user form.  Might need to refresh your list of users once the new form has been completed and the dialog is closed.